# Mysql counter field. counter + 1

Tags: mysql

have this simple code:

```
UPDATE counter SET c= c +1 where id = 1;
```

and it doesn't work where there is null in the c field in the begining.
it works only when there is some number entered already, also 0.
was trying something like:

```
CAST(c AS UNSIGNED) + 1
```

but it also doesnt work.
what do I do wrong here?
cannot change the c field value to 0 for default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `IFNULL`::

```
UPDATE counter SET c= ifnull(c,0) +1 where id = 1;
```